# Can I serialize metadata to quickly build a delegate

Tags: c#, serialization, delegates

I have a test harness which compiles several delegates specific to the types it is testing.  The delegates do things which would otherwise be very heavy in reflection (and thus, slow).

The delegates themselves run very fast once they're built.  The problem is that discovering all the metadata about the type under test and building the delegates to begin with is *really slow*.  Is there a way I can serialize all the metadata and use it to quickly rebuild the delegates?  I would need a quick way to hash the incoming types under test to see if they had changed.  If yes, rebuild the metadata; if not, use the serialized version.